# Being blocked from flagging without any warning

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I have been blocked from flagging due to getting multiple declines.

I did not expect that having different point of views with the moderators will lead to be blocked from flagging questions.

Moreover, I did not get any warning before being blocked.

For example, flagging too off-topic answers as "not an answer" was declined and told to not flag this kind of answers. If I should not flag this kind of answers, why there is an option for flagging not related answers?

I suggest that some features should be added to StackExchange for giving instructional tips and hints in order to reduce the need for searching the web for possible regulations of StackExchange.

Comment: Moderators don't control who gets flag-blocked and it sounds like this is an automated system. I wasn't even aware that this was a feature. You can suggest feature requests at [meta.se]

Comment: Regarding "not an answer", the flag is typically used for cases where new users post a new question as an answer, or if they post an edit to their question as an answer or if the answer is otherwise outright spam. Moderators aren't subject matter experts in all topics, so it is not easy for us to evaluate the merits of answers. Easiest option would be to downvote the answer. Users with >20k rep can also vote to delete an answer (score 0 and below), so for egregiously wrong answers (but still an "answer" and not spam), you can solicit support in chat.

Comment: @Alex97 Is the blocking permanent? Which answers did you flag?

Comment: Sorry for my incomplete information and thank you for your answers. The blocking has been for 7 days. These are some of the messages I have received in the "helpful flags" sections: 
1. I flagger for reopening a clearer question that was closed as duplicate  " declined - The two questions are near identical and I'm not seeing a better answer. One option is to place a "bounty" on the older question with more views and ask for a better answer"

Comment: 2. Flagging because someone gave a completely wrong answer under two of my questions (I raised flag for both) : " declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer" 

I have received five declines in one day.
@rhermans

Comment: @Alex97 For context, I am the mod that declined your flags that day. My intent in declining was not to be punitive (I didn't know these bans existed), and I didn't realize they all came from one person. I reviewed the flags question by question and addressed each based on its merits. I often leave notes if there's something to add to educate or provide context, but not everyone reads the flag messages, so I appreciate you doing that! While we can't change the flag outcome, you can always bring it to chat and ask the community's feedback and/or support in overturning the decision (on the post).

Comment: Thanks. How can I ask the community's feedback or support in overturning the decision on the post? @rm-rf

Comment: Let's talk in the [chat]. Please link to the questions, and accept that anybody starting is bound to make mistakes and will have one or two new things to learn. After some feedback, you can post a new question, this time an [excellent](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/asking) one.